# How to retrieve stored image in sql database in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database and one of its columns is in Image data type. I can store Image in database but I can't retrieve it. I want to retrive Image for each logged in user. I used this code:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage()
{
    var userID = GetUserID();
    var advert = from ad in StoreDb.Ads where ad.UserId == userID select ad.AdImage;
    return File(advert, "Image");     
}
```

But got this error:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'string'    C:\Users\Tena\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication6\MvcApplication6\Controllers\Default3Controller.cs   92  25  MvcApplication6

The problem is that advert is in

```
System.Linq.IQueryable<>byte[]
```

format but File needs `byte[]` format. What should I do now? Any answer is helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the LINQ query isn't being evaluated and the query as it stands could theoretically return more than one result (hence it's an `IQueryable`).

In fact the query doesn't look right as presumably there will be more than one advert for a particular user and I wouldn't expect the adverts to be stored according to user in any case, but I don't know anything about your data structure, so I'll just try to help you make the query work and you can refine it later.

Try changing this line:

```
var advert = from ad in StoreDb.Ads where ad.UserId == userID select ad.AdImage;
```

to this:

```
var advert = (from ad in StoreDb.Ads where ad.UserId == userID select ad.AdImage).FirstOrDefault();
```

I could give you other tips around how to do this, but try that first and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. yes it was my fault. There were more than one image for user, When I deleted them from databse it works perfect.

Comment: Is there better way to do this?

Comment: Other than making a generic file retrieval function that takes an ID and gets the file, your method actually looks fine. I have bits of code like this in my MVC projects: `return File(file.ImageData, file.MimeType);` It might be helpful to give your controllers more meaningful names (the error message contains a reference to `Default3Controller.cs`).

Answer (score 2):

I'not sure, this is the way to go for this problem. I usually implement a custom http handler, which expects some id (e.g. userid), connects to the database, fetches the picture and returns a stream of bytes with the correct mime type of the picture.

In the "view" i just create an image tag with the url of the http handler as image source.

Comment: @ Mithrandir: Thank for your answer, but I'm new in mvc and didn't work with this solution yet. But Thank you and I will learn it.